# Angular Material Autocomplete component with Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, autocomplete, ionic2, angular-material2

Is is possible to use https://material.angular.io/components/component/autocomplete in Ionic 2 App? Unfortunately Ionic 2 doesn't provide an autocomplete component so far. 
If it's possible - what are the steps to integrate it and make it work?

Comment: What about [searchbar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#searchbar) ?

Comment: @gerdi I'd like to have to input possibilities: Select a value from a list (from db) or enter a new value and save it to db. I don't want display the whole list in the form.

Comment: you dont have to show the whole list. You can add an `*ngIf` that only displays the data once the user has starting typing. As for adding it as a new item you can just add a icon to the right and add a `(click)="addInputValue()"`. IMHO you can actually do a lot more with the searchbar then you can the angular material autocomplete